# Adobe Edge performance / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, adobe-edge

I am working on an Adobe Edge animation stagnating at 10-15 fps. It's a pretty complex animation playing full screen, with a lot of big elements.

But the weird thing is that looking at Chrome's Timeline, it seems that most of the time on each frame is spent at scripting (about ~50ms), and not at rendering or painting.

[image: timeline]

I had a detailed look at Edge's javascript source, there is no clear bottleneck in it, but how is it possible that moving a bunch of dom elements take 50ms each frame? I'd prefer to find something fishy here than trying to get my hands dirty with the animation itself (which has not been made by me)